# async await typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using async and await for getting response from an api
but when I using it with react type script it keeps

**TS2339: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'AxiosResponse<any, any>'.**

I am following a course but it seems he work in older version
is there any way to achieve that

here is my function for submit form

```
const submitRegister = async (e: SyntheticEvent)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const { email:email } = await axios.post('http://lovalhost/8000');
}
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: There's probably a `data` property IIRC, so it would look like `const { data: { email } } = ...`

Answer (score 1):

> 'http://lovalhost/8000'

Do you mean 'localhost:8000'?

> const { email:email } = await axios.post()

Here you are destructing the response for the `email` property.  If you look at the actual response you will find that you are probably looking for `response.data.email`

Try using .then and .catch as well.

```
const email = await axios.post('http://lovalhost/8000').then(({data}) => data.email).catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the `data` object within the response as can be seen here https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema

Try something like this:

```
const { data } = await axios.post('http://lovalhost/8000');
const { email } = data
```

or maybe store the `response` object because that will also have information about the response status etc.

```
try {
    const response = await axios.post('http://lovalhost/8000');

    if (response.status != 200) {
       // throw
    }

    const { email } = response.data
    return email
}
catch (ex) {
    console.error(ex)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The response from `await axiosPost(...)` will be an object containing a `data`  key that holds the data returned from the request.

```
const response = await axios.post('http://lovalhost/8000');
console.log(response.data.email) // this is where your email value will be (in case the request is succesful)
```

You can also let typescript know what your response data will look like, by adding the type to the call.

```
const response = await axios.post<{email: string}>('http://lovalhost/8000');
```